# why this program goes to infine loop, im trying to do an ring counter

Tags: vhdl, counter

[image: srff]

```
 library ieee;
 use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 entity ccou is
  port(clk2 : in bit;
    qc: out bit_vector(3 downto 0);
    qnc: out bit_vector(3 downto 0));
  end entity;
 architecture a_ccou of ccou is
  component dfff
   port(d,clk1:in bit;
        qd,qnd:out bit);
  end component;
  signal tqc,tqnc: bit_vector(3 downto 0);
   begin
    g1 : dfff port map(tqnc(3),clk2,tqc(0),tqnc(0));
    g2 : dfff port map(tqc(0),clk2,tqc(1),tqnc(1));
    g3 : dfff port map(tqc(1),clk2,tqc(2),tqnc(2));
    g4 : dfff port map(tqc(2),clk2,tqc(3),tqnc(3));
    qc(3 downto 0) <= tqc(3 downto 0);
    qnc(3 downto 0) <= tqnc(3 downto 0);
 end architecture;
```

I used structural modelling to design a ring counter, with d flip flop as component. The problem is the program goes to infinite loop. I tried replacing tqnc(3) with '1' or '0' the program runs for finite time but wrong output. Whats the problem and help me rectify it.

and the code for sr flip flop is

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity srfff is
 port(s,r,clk: in bit;
   q,qn:out bit);
end srfff;
architecture a_srff of srfff is
 component nnand
  port(a,b:in bit;
     c:inout bit);
 end component;
 signal ts,tr : bit;
 signal tq,tqn: bit;
 begin
  g1 : nnand port map(s,clk,ts);
  g2 : nnand port map(r,clk,tr);
  g3 : nnand port map(ts,tqn,tq);
  g4 : nnand port map(tr,tq,tqn);
  q <= tq;
  qn <=tqn;
end a_srff;
```

Comment: The question does not contain enough information; please see [Help Center - 1. Questions seeking debugging help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are your DFF outputs qd, qnd inout instead of out only? Same for CCOU outputs...

Comment: basically i developed dff from a sr ff with gate level design, where q and qn are used as inputs for the first nand gates, and henceforth they are declared as inout, i will post circuit from which i constructed an sr ff, then i negated the value of d to r input.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `inout`, which implies a tristate buffer which is not always supported for synthesis (except on toplevel). The correct way to do this is use a signal inside your architecture for the port, and add the assignment `qd <= qd_i;`.

Comment: @Jonathan  Drolet, i changed the mode, but the simulation again goes to infinite loop and output waveform is 1111, but when i pass '1' instead of cqnd i get the output, i.e, 1111.

Comment: @iBharath This was not meant as a fix to your issue, but a general design comment. As Morten Zilmer pointed out, your question does not contain enough information to figure out the problem.

Comment: ok, edited is the actual code after using only 'out' mode instead of 'inout'.

Comment: Notice this question has been asked before, See [Undefined output of Ring Counter Test waveform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931496/undefined-output-of-ring-counter-test-waveform/), and was apparently not satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily the final answer. You haven't supplied enough information with your question to determine whether your oscillation is caused by one or both of two possible causes.

I had made changes to your originally supplied code:

```
entity dfff is
    port (
        d,clk1:    in    bit;
        qd,qnd:    inout bit
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of dfff is

begin
    process (clk1)
    begin
        if clk1'event and clk1 = '1' then
            qd  <= d;
            qnd <= not d;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;


-- library ieee;
-- use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity ccou is
    port (
        clk2:           in  bit;
        qa,qb,qc:       out bit; -- inout
        cqd:            out bit;     -- inout
        qna,qnb,qnc:    out bit; --inout
        cqnd:           out bit  -- inout bit := '1' -- ); -- inout
    );
end entity;

architecture a_ccou of ccou is
    component dfff
        port (
            d,clk1: in    bit;
            qd,qnd: inout bit
        );
    end component;

--    signal ta: bit;

    signal iqa, iqb, iqc, icqd:  bit;
    signal iqna, iqnb, iqnc, icqnd: bit;
begin
    qa <= iqa;
    qb <= iqb;
    qc <= iqc;
    cqd <= icqd;
    qna <= iqna;
    qnb <= iqnb;
    qnc <= iqnc;
    cqnd <= icqnd;

g1: dfff port map (icqnd, clk2,  iqa,  iqna);
g2: dfff port map (iqa,   clk2,  iqb,  iqnb);
g3: dfff port map (iqb,   clk2,  iqc,  iqnc);
g4: dfff port map (iqc,   clk2, icqd, icqnd);
end architecture;

entity ccou_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of ccou_tb is
    signal clk2: bit;
    signal qa, qb, qc, cqd, qna, qnb, qnc, cqnd: bit;
begin
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk2 <= not clk2;
    end process;

DUT:
    entity work.ccou
        port map (
            clk2 => clk2,
            qa => qa,
            qb => qb,
            qc => qc,
            cqd => cqd,
            qna => qna,
            qnb => qnb,
            qnc =>  qnc,
            cqnd => cqnd
        );

end architecture;
```

The changes provided mode out on `ccou`, adding internal signals, a behavioral model of the `dfff` flip flop and, a testbench.

That produced:

[image: ring counter]
*(clickable)*

This is pretty much telling us you have a problem with your `dfff` flip flop entity/architecture.  Note the behavioral `dfff` model uses an edge clock.

Note your added chalkboard drawing image matches

[image: Fig2-9]

from the **Microarchitecture of Pipelined and Superscalar Computers**, 1999 by Amos R. Omandi. And represents a D Latch, not an edge sensitive flip flop.

**S R latch feedback oscillation**
If your `dfff` is indeed based on your chalkboard representation one source of oscillation can be remedied by unbalancing the Q BAR to S and Q to R delays on the R S latch or by using a [consensus term](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/160000/how-can-i-implement-a-simple-q-only-d-latch-using-vhdl/160039#160039) in an Earle latch.

Essentially when `clk1` is false in your `dfff` implementation SR latch might oscillate because the feed back inputs have events at the same time.

The Earle latch:

[image: Earle latch]

uses a consensus term (the middle AND gate) to dampen S R latch oscillation, keeping the output high when the input is high and represents a real world solution that happens to lend itself to simulation.

In device physics we also have the ability to unbalance delays be trimming trace capacitance or transistor size.

Here the S R latch feedback oscillation is a modelling shortcoming that is useful for teaching real design issues.

**Enabled Ring delay plus inversion**
Unfortunately the ring counter implemented with 'transparent' latches is also susceptible to an oscillation when `clk1` (the enable) is true and the ring feedback (`g4` `qnd` output to `g1` `d` input) provides inversion.

We used to call this a striking oscillator, a gated relaxation oscillator.

Fixing the ring feedback oscillation requires using an edge sensitive flip flop or non-overlapping clocks between successive flip flops, preventing a less than 4 clock delay around ring.

See the Wikipedia [Master–slave edge-triggered D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Master.E2.80.93slave_edge-triggered_D_flip-flop) [flip-flop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)).

A master slave flip flop is implemented with two successive D latches one operating off one phase of the clock (as an enable) and the other off the opposite phase.

These can have requirements for unbalanced feedback delay in the S R latches.  The gate level representation shown provides that, plus there are other representations that minimize gate delays.

About now you might get the idea this is a hardware design issue.